# Missing required module 'Firebase' for Unit test

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, unit-testing

i added Unit test target to existing project, when i `@testable import Product_Module_Name` in test class i am getting

> Missing required module 'Firebase'

i am using firebase pod in the project
*tried adding*   `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = "${PODS_ROOT}/Firebase/CoreOnly/Sources"` in Build Settings and added

```
target 'TestTargetName' do
  inherit! :search_paths
end
```

in pod file.
But still getting error **Missing required module 'Firebase'**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
target 'GRCReportsTests' do
  inherit! :search_paths
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
end
```

This solved my issue

Answer (score 7):

I don't use CocoaPods but SPM.
For me the issue was with the wrong `TEST_HOST` value.
After creating a new project in Xcode 14, the default value was set to:
`TEST_HOST = "$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/YourApp.app/$(BUNDLE_EXECUTABLE_FOLDER_PATH)/YourApp";`
and it caused the final path to have an extra slash - `build/Debug-iphoneos/YourApp.app//YourApp`

What worked for me is removing `/$(BUNDLE_EXECUTABLE_FOLDER_PATH)` from the `TEST_HOST`

Comment: This helped me so much! I know this was unrelated to the OPs question but I thank you for providing this response.

Comment: This helped me too.  Exactly the problem I had.  Thank you.